# Best way to approach a 2-sided user interface with Flask?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I have been working on this for a while now, and after combing through dozens of threads and following numerous tutorials, have decided to ask about my specific problem.

I am somewhat inexperienced with coding, and especially new to developing with Flask, but will do my best to try to explain my problem and my attempts thus far. I'm also new to StackOverflow, so forgive me if the way I'm phrasing this question isn't correct!

I am building an application with 2 sides — picture Uber, where you can sign up to either drive or ride. From now on I will be referring to these roles as 'x' and 'y'.

I'm not sure what the best approach is to create these two roles. I have worked with flask-login, flask-security, and flask-admin but am still unsure how to implement specific roles.

Right now, I have two separate sign up forms set up, at /register for user type x and /signup for user type y. This doesn't seem ideal, but again, I don't know how else to structure this.

I am using [mLab](https://mlab.com/) to store my data, and I already have information stored in 2 collections in this database — for further purposes db.x and db.y — carried over from the way the site was previously structured.

I originally followed a tutorial to find a way to register type x users, but have been struggling to add a separate category for type Y. When I fill out the registration form for *y* as a test, the data is automatically stored in db.x

I was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the flask-login LoginManager to send data to different databases?

for reference:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.objects(pk=user_id).first()
```

Here's what I have started to set up, but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction here. (I changed the types I set up to x and y here for readability)

```
class x(UserMixin, dbapp.Investors):
    meta = {'collection': 'x'}
    meta = {'type': 'x'}
    email = dbapp.StringField(max_length=30)
    password = dbapp.StringField()
    role = user_datastore.add_role_to_user(email, 'x')

class y(UserMixin, dbapp.Startups):
    meta = {'collection': 'y'}
    meta = {'type': 'y'}
    category = dbapp.StringField()
    description = dbapp.StringField(max_length=150)
    location = dbapp.StringField()
    image = dbapp.StringField()
    email = dbapp.StringField(max_length=30)
    password = dbapp.StringField()
    role = user_datastore.add_role_to_user(email, 'y')
```

For those who have worked on similar projects/encountered similar issues: what is the best way to deal with this problem?

Basically: how do I register one type of user to db.x and the other to db.y ? The reason I want to keep them separated is that anonymous users will still be able to access data from db.y and it would make my life easier to not have to change too much of the existing framework.

Thanks in advance! - Isabella

Comment: Try the Flask-User lib, it wraps Flask-Login and provides a way to an easier solution of your problem.

Comment: @Fian - I'll check that out now. Do you think that will make it possible to register different types of users in different collections within the same database?

Comment: As I can see, it's even possible with just Flask-login: in load_user make a query to 2 collections one by one and return user if it exists as mongo's ids are cross-db unique.